# ClientId causes NullReferenceException

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a repeater inside of which I have some controls one of which is a textbox. I am trying to get the textbox with jquery, my code looking like this:

```
$("#<%= ((TextBox)myRpt.FindControl("tbText")).ClientID %>").click(function (event) {});
```

but I always get a nullReferenceException. 
Anyone has any idea what could cause this?

The repeater looks similar to this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRpt" runat="server" onitemdatabound="myRpt_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate> </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate> /*some controls*/
        <td id="tdX" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbText" runat="server" ClientIDMode = "Static"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: You are generating same id `tbText` for all TextBox, try to make it different  and unique for all textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an `ASP.NET repeater` control, thus all the controls inside repeater  will repeat itself and so the textboxes, so you will have Ids appended with 1,2,,and so on. So better use class for your textbox instead and apply function like this:-

```
$('.yourTextboxClassName').click(function() {
   //Your code goes here
   //You can refer to the current textbox using $(this)
});
```